# TinyMCE Image URL select

Tags: file-upload, tinymce

I have written my own image uploader for TinyMCE, but I am left with one dilemma: how do I select the image to show in the "Image URL" field of the TinyMCE advimage popup?

My image uploader opens in another popup when I click the button next to the "Image URL" field. So I need to get the image url from my popup and insert it in the other popup in that field. I can get the path very easy, but I don't know how to insert it in the other place.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the jQuery build, here is part of the code I'm using from within the custom filebrowser:

```
$('.my-image').click(function() {// Change this to your event/selector

    var $src = $(this).val();// Change this to whatever the image path is
    if ( ! $src) return false;

    // Find the iframe within the popup
    var $input = $(window.top.document)
    .find('iframe[src*="advimage/image.htm"]')
    .contents()
    .find('input#src');

    // Trigger the preview and fill in the image dimensions
    $input.val($src).change();

    return false;
});
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it's been working for me for years. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hehehe, this is just the idea I got after I submitted the question! I have one problem, though: the code with `window.top.document` returns the same window, not the window with the image field :( Oh.. btw: I am using popups, not iframes.

Comment: Well, I'm also using jQuery UI for the dialog windows, so the iframe is actually part of the top window. You'll have to adjust this to suit your specific situation - this was mostly to give you an idea and let you know that this is certainly possible. My personal implementation is really tricked out so I gave you a snippet. Instead of targeting the iframe, just target whatever element the form is in. You'll also need something to close the popup after the selection is made.

Comment: Ok, I have just loaded the 'inlinepopups' plugin and bam! it worked :) Now I need to figure out how to close my little popup. Do you know any tricks for this too?

Comment: To close your custom dialog? I would have no idea without seeing the code. Try `$(my_popup_element).remove()`

Comment: Yeah, that works, but I was thinking of triggering the click event on the 'x', but nothing happens when I do. `mouseup` doesn't do anything, either. Strange... any idea to what event is the close operation bind? And yes, I'm working with the right element.

Comment: You didn't answer my last question, but can't blame you, I asked a lot :P Thanks a lot! You have been of great help :)

Comment: Not sure Marian, maybe a good topic for [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).