# Trigger the event which happens when I click the 'x' button on a TinyMCE modal dialog (like the advimage dialog)

Tags: modal-dialog, tinymce

Please see this comment and the rest of the thread: [question]: [TinyMCE Image URL select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537709/tinymce-image-url-select/6537842#comment-7703879)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'x'-Button element is the element you get using `$(".mceClose")`. So you are able to assign an event handler there (you need to assign the handler when the dialog is open/visible) else you won't find such an element and the assignment will fail. Here it is:

```
$(".mceClose").click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know which element it is. I want to trigger the close the dialog just like you click the 'x' button, not assign an event to it. I tried triggering a few events, like `$(".mceClose").click()` or `$(".mceClose").mousedown()` and more, but they do nothing. I wonder why...

Comment: i was able to trigger $(".mceClose").click() - the alert works (FF3.6.18)

Comment: No no, I don't want to add that event you wrote. I want to trigger whatever event is causing the dialog to close.

Comment: For this i suggest you download the tinymce developement version which contains all source files. There you should have a closer look into the inlinepopup plugin (directory tiny_mce\plugins\inlinepopups\editor_plugin_src.js). line 224 and following will be interesting to you (the click event is added there)

Comment: It seems like a simple `$(".mceClose").click()` doesn't work, but I have found a way around this. Here is an example: `$('.mceClose').get(n).click();` where n is the index (starts at 0) of the `.mceClose` you want to "click".