# Event when tinymce plugin dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

`tinymce.PluginManager` will open a dialog using `windowManager.open()`. The dialog can be closed manually by using `windowManager.close()`.  This is described by http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.Plugin.  The dialog can also be closed by clicking the "X" in the top right corner.

I would like to execute some script whenever the dialog is closed.  Seems to me there are two options.

Option 1.  Ideally, I can add a callback which would execute whenever ever the dialog is closed.  I have searched the documentation, but cannot find out whether this is possible.

Option 2.  When ever I manually close the dialog using `windowManager.close()`, I can add the desired script directly before doing so.  It is when the user clicks the X has got me stumped.

[Trigger the event which happens when I click the 'x' button on a TinyMCE modal dialog (like the advimage dialog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540901/trigger-the-event-which-happens-when-i-click-the-x-button-on-a-tinymce-modal-d) describes adding an event handler to the X button being clicked.  Problem is the event cannot be associated until the dialog is open, and there doesn't seem to be an on open dialog event I can do it at.

How can I execute code whenever the TinyMCE plugin dialog is closed?  Thank you

```
$(".mceClose").click(function() {
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

Comment: This may help http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onRemove

Comment: @Manish.  Thank you, but this is the editor, and not the plugin dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in [API reference](http://api.tinymcesupport.com/tinymce/WindowManager), close method fires onClose event. So you can try something like:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.onClose.add(function() {...})
```

Comment: Your link does not lead to the API reference but to a page you might be involved

Comment: onClose is not a function (tinyMce 4.5.6)

Answer (score 11):

To be precise you should add onClose function as the following:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
    ...
    onClose: function() {

    }
});
```

It cost me a lot of time to find right solution. Hope it will help.

Comment: best solution as the first selected answer will fail if more than 2 popup windows are open